# Accent mark issue with Freshdesk/Freshchat

Tags: html, special-characters, diacritics, freshdesk

I have implemented Freshchat following the documentation at https://developers.freshchat.com/. This is for a website that is in Spanish. In my code, I have used this block that includes accent marks because the text is in Spanish:

```
channel_response: {
    offline: 'Nos hemos retirado. Por favor d&eacute;janos un mensaje.',
    online: {
        minutes: {
            one: "Contestando en aproximadamente {!time!} minutos.",
            more: "Respuestas típicamente en {!time!} minutos."
        }
        ..........
        ..........
        ..........
    }
}
```

The problem is that is I use `more: "Respuestas típicamente en {!time!} minutos."`, I see this:

[image]

If I use `more: "Respuestas t&iacute;picamente en {!time!} minutos."`, I see this:

[image]

In any case, the accent mark does not display correctly. I am already using this:

```
<script>
    window.fcWidget.init({
        token: "[token string]",
        host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com",
        locale: "es",
        ..........
        ..........
        ..........
    });
</script>
```

Since I am using `locale: "es"`, I was expecting for accent marks to be recognized without problems. Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading https://support.freshchat.com/support/solutions/articles/232388-languages-supported-by-freshchat, I see this:

[image]

I am using the "Blossom" plan. They provide the multiple language feature only for the "Estate" plan. This is confirmed in the following image:

[image]